# How secure is (permanent) cookie-only authentication?

Tags: authentication, cookies

I'm making an webapp which have to maintain some user specific data, so authentication is needed. My app is not anything mission critical. As this is the case, I thought of removing the whole sign-up/sign-in as it acts as a big barrier for a visitor. Instead the authentication is based solely on cookies. When they access my app, a cookie is set and they are logged in. All their activities are stored in db across their cookie value. So whenever they visit again from the same browser, they will get their customized pages.

I know that they can't browse from another device, or if they clear cookies they can't recover account. Let's say these won't be problem for me, as there are going to be a handful of initial users. Incase if they face such trouble accessing, I could give them support.

So is it advisible to have cookie only authentication? And also leaving the cookie unchanged (permanent) is fine?

Comment: I believe register plus login is a way lower hassle than losing the entire account when I clear cookies or change browser/device. Even if this is just a PoC, start the right way. Building something that does not scale will bite you back, hard, when you got more users and have to stop everything to bake something so basic as regular accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The security of your approach depends on the ability to protect the cookie against misuse by others - similar to how the security of credential based methods (i.e. username and password) depends on the ability to protect these credentials.

Only, nothing is known about your ability to protect the cookie. It is not known if you use HTTPS to protect against extracting the cookie by sniffing the connection. Neither is known if the cookie is httpOnly to protect against extractions by XSS attacks. It is also not known if attacks to the users system are part of the threats you need to worry about since of course this permanent cookie need to be somehow stored at the users system. And then there might be server side problems which might cause cookies to be leaked too.

In summary: it might be safe enough for your specific use case or it might be not. Too few is known about the use case and how the cookie is protected on the client, in transit and on the server.

Comment: Ofcourse the site will be using https. The cookie will be http only and secure cookie too (just in case if I had any http paths by mistake). There won't be any bigtime attackers going to be targeting my users because they are not going to gain much by taking over the account. The data users, are going to save are not much sensitive but still should not be public (something like their to-do list), even if these data is stolen or the data is deleted in a rare case, its okay , the user will create it again.

Comment: @ManiBharathy: in this case it is probably secure enough